# if $X$ is independent of $Y_1....Y_n$, is it independent of $f(Y_1,..Y_n)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

So we have the conclusion that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are independent (g, h measurable?), is it still true that for general case $X$ independent of $g(Y_1,..Y_n)$, where $Y_i$ are themselves not independent to each other.

I don't see how this is duplicate with that of showing $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are independent.

If it is not generally true, can we at least show however, $X$ is independent of the sum of $Y_i$?

Let me add some more condition, what about $X$ and $Y_i$ are all gaussians? And the function $g$ $h$ are nice smooth functions.

Essentially, I just want to show $X$ is independent of sum of $Y_i$.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate, since I am asking the joint, it is true for two single r.v. but how about the joint case?

Comment: @user365239 How do you show that?

Comment: @user365239 we only know $X$ is independent of each $Y_i$, $Y_i$ are not mutually independent.

Comment: @user365239  it's in the question "where $Y_i$ are themselves not independent to each other."

Comment: Sorry i misread

Comment: Do you assume that $X$ is independent of $(Y_1,...,Y_n)$?

Comment: @d.k.o. no, that is actually exactly what I want to show. And can we at least $X$ is independent of the sum of $Y_i$?

Comment: @jack The info you added significantly changed the initial question for which you got an answer.

Comment: Your hypothesis is unclear: is it (a) that $X$ is independent of $Y=(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$, or (b) that $X$ is independent of $Y_k$, for each $k$? If (a) then $X$ is trivially independent of $Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$. If (b) then $X$ may not be independent of $Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$.

Comment: @Did it is (b).

Comment: Then the usual (counter-)examples apply.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sigma(X)$ is independent of $\sigma(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$, then $X$ is independent of any measurable function of $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$. If not, here is a counterexample:

Let $Y_i=1_{A_i}$, $i=1,2$ s.t. $\mathsf{P}(A_i)=1/2$ and $A_1$ is independent of $A_2$. Then $X=1\{Y_1+Y_2 \text{ is even}\}$ is independent of $Y_i$, however, $X$ is not independent of a function of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$,

Comment: @N.. Compute $\mathsf{P}(X=a,Y=b)$ and compare it to $\mathsf{P}(X=a)\mathsf{P}(Y=b)$ for $a,b\in \{0,1\}$...

Comment: @N.. I'm not sure what you are asking about.